# How to display pic on the web using Android device which os is 2.3

Tags: android, html

Well. I want to upload an image to the web and see it soon on the web not connecting with the server.

I know some ways like FileReader, Canvas API. But the two ways are not compatible with Android device which os is 2.3.

Is there other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You want to upload an image and then see it there without connecting to the server?

Comment: Can we make pancakes without being connected to internet ? Hope so.

Comment: Well.I said not connecting with the server means display the pic just in the front-end environment.

We may upload the image to the server, and the server response you a base64 or the url of the pic.  But I don't use this method.

Comment: You want to display it on an Android application, or a web browser ? Your problem is not super clear.

Comment: We'll let you try things first, post your findings and your attempts here (with code of course) and you'll get a faster, more reliable awnser
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link and decide whether to use a webview or not?

[WebView Version and Features Comparision Chart for Android Versions](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_)